# Windows 2008 R2 SNMP Virtual & Physical Memory

Tags: windows, snmp

Our network monitoring system ([WhatsUp Gold from ipswitch](https://www.ipswitch.com/application-and-network-monitoring/whatsup-gold)) is reporting our memory backwards.  The system is reporting:

Virtual Memory - 16 GB
Physical Memory - 8 GB

The server (Windows 2008 R2) has 16 GB of memory which is hosted in an VMWare ESX environment.  I've tried exploring the associated OID space but haven't been able to verify the associated values with WUG.  Are there any free SNMP tools out there to look up SNMP OID values for a system to double check what is being reported by the server?  Any other ideas why these readings appear backwards?

Thank You,
Eric

Comment: Can you capture the incoming SNMP UDP packet before it gets to What's up? That will tell you if the packet is coming in like that or if What's Up is manipulating it after it gets to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot since they are hosted production systems.